# Smallest sphere intersecting lines in R^3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have N lines in R^3 (that are very likely skew). I'm looking for an efficient method of computing the radius (and position) of the smallest sphere that intersects every line.

I suspect that there's a solution related to the 'smallest sphere enclosing points' problem, but I failed to find it.

(The purpose is to be able to do bundle adjustment without needing to make the inferred point positions visible to the optimizer).

Comment: If the lines were parallel, this would reduce to the smallest circle problem in the plane, which is solvable in linear time. I suggest trying to generalize some of the algorithms for the smallest circle problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance from a point to a line is a convex function, and the maximum of convex functions in convex, so locating a point that minimizes the maximum of its distances to the lines is a convex problem, therefore it should be relatively easy to solve using modern software for convex optimization.

Comment: Wait what?  The maximum of convex functions needn't be convex.  For example, in one dimension, $ max(x, -x) $ is not convex despite that $ x $ and $ -x $ both are.


Comment: How is $max(x,-x)$ not convex?

Comment: Make it the square of the distance, so it's convex *upward*,
and then the maximum satisfies the same condition.


Comment: Huh?  Convex is convex "upward".  Either the distance or the square of the distance is convex.  The maximum of convex functions is always convex.

Comment: Sorry, I hallucinated that the distance to a line rather than a point
is not convex upwards.  [Not sure if "convex" means up or down $-$
apparently Z.Ambrus took it to mean down $-$ but I try always specify
the direction when I write "convex", as I specify whether a $2 \times 3$
matrix has 2 rows and 3 columns or vice versa: even if there's a "correct"
convention, enough readers will assume the opposite that it pays to specify.]
Still, In practice you'd compute with the squared distance.


Answer (score 3):

Here is a starting point. For each line $L$ in $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\bR^3$ we denote by $C_r(L)$ the cylinder of axis $L$ and radius $R$. Given  $N$ lines you need to find  the smallest $r$ such that the convex sets $C_r(L_1),\dotsc, C_r(L_N)$ have nonempty overlap.

According to Helly's theorem,  a collection of convex subsets  in $\bR^k$ has nonempty overlap if and only if, any subcollection of $k+1$ subsets in that  collection has a nonempty overlap. Thus, in your case, you need to make sure  that  any four cylinders in your collection  have nonempty overlap.

This reduces the problem to $N=4$ which looks less scary, yet still challenging.

If we are given $4$-lines  $L_1,\dotsc, L_4$ passing through   distinct point $p_1,\dotsc, p_4$  and spanned by the unit vector $\newcommand{\bu}{\boldsymbol{u}}$ $\bu_1,\dotsc,\bu_4$, then the distance  from a point $x$ to the line $L_k$ is achived along a segment $[x, y]$ where,

$$y\in L_k,\;\; [x,y]\perp L_k. $$

This means

$$y= p_k+t\bu_k,\;\;  (x-p_k -t\bu_k, \cdot \bu_k)=0, $$

so that

$$ t=(x-p_k, \bu_k),\;\; y= p_k +(x-p_k, \bu_k)\bu_k, $$

$${\rm dist}(x, L_k)^2=\bigl| x-p_k -(x-p_k,\bu_k)\bu_k\;\bigr|^2=|x-p_k|^2-(x-p_k,\bu_k)^2. $$

At this point some ugly, but  machine approachable algebra is needed.

Comment: we may also assume $(p_k,v_k)=0$, to simplify another little bit.

Comment: "According to Helly's theorem, a collection of convex subsets in Rk has nonempty overlap if and only if, any subcollection of k+1 subsets in that collection has a nonempty overlap"

Is this really "any"? I think the theorem is ".. iff _every_ subcollection ..."

Comment: This is a matter of semantics that may not be decidable in this forum. Let me stipulate that "any" refers to the universal  quantifier, as in the phrase "for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists... "